# Understanding the vector-valued MVT

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I see that the Wikipedia page this description of the vector-valued MVT: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

For a continuous ${\bf f}:[a,b]\to \Bbb R^m$ differentiable on $(a,b)$, there exists $x\in (a,b)$ such that $|{\bf f}'(x)| \ge \frac{1}{b-a}|{\bf f}(b)-{\bf f}(a)|$.

But I also read this document: [https://www.geneseo.edu/~aguilar/public/notes/Real-Analysis-HTML/ch10-multivariable-differential-calculus.html](https://www.geneseo.edu/%7Eaguilar/public/notes/Real-Analysis-HTML/ch10-multivariable-differential-calculus.html)

Corollary 10.2.9: Let $U\subseteq \Bbb R^m$ be open and assume $F=(f_1,\dots,f_m):U\to \Bbb R^m$ is differentiable on $U$.  Let $x,y\in U$ and suppose that the line segment joining $x,y$ is contained entirely in $U$.  Then there exist $c_1,\dots,c_m\in U$ on the line segment joining $x,y$ such that
$$ f_i(y)-f_i(x) = Df_i(c_i)(y-x) \text{ for } i = 1,\dots,m$$
I'm trying to understand how one of these only gives an inequality while the other one is able to state equality.

In Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* it seems like, for this same basic theorem, he too uses an inequality rather than an equality.  Is there a mistake in the second resources which uses the equality, or am I misunderstanding some additional assumption that is at work in one version which is not in another?

Comment: One of the results deals with line segments only. Do you see where that hypothesis is used in the proof?

Comment: @leslietownes Am I wrong to think that the Wikipedia article is implicitly about segments since it takes place on the segment $[a,b]$?  I see where segments are used in the second linked document, but I'm not seeing why anything said there couldn't just as well be said in the other case.

Comment: Both results are about "curves," i.e., the images of intervals $[a,b]$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ (which in general might, or might not, be line segments).  In the Rudin result it is not assumed that the image of the interval (i.e. the set $\{f(t): t \in [a,b]\}$) is a line segment in $\mathbb{R}^m$.  In the other linked result, it is.  In general, if $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is a curve, and $t \in (a,b)$, there is no reason to expect $f(t)$ to be on the line segment between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ (consider a parametrization of a semicircle in $\mathbb{R}^2$, for example).